# Django How add math result from form in Model.objects.create

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to divide one value by another from the form and write the result. But it doesn't work

```
def add_project(request):
    form_address = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    form_project = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)
    form_detail = ProjectDetailForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_address.is_valid() and form_project.is_valid() and form_detail.is_valid():
            address_clean = form_address.cleaned_data
            project_clean = form_project.cleaned_data
            detail_clean = form_detail .cleaned_data

            a = Address.objects.update_or_create(**address_clean)

            p = Project.objects.create(
                address = a[0],
                manager = request.user,
                file = project_clean['file'],
                sq = project_clean['sq'],
                rent_tax = project_clean['rent_tax']
            )

            sq_price = project_clean['rent_tax'] / project_clean['sq']

            ProjectDetail.objects.create(
                project = p,
                sq_price = sq_price,
                **detail_clean
            )
            return redirect("crm:homepage")

    context = {'form_address':form_address, 'form_project':form_project, 'form_detail':form_detail,}

    return render(request, 'crm/add_project.html', context)
```

I try

```
sq_price = project_clean['rent_tax'] / project_clean['sq']
```

The print command outputs a number. But Django says it is an error:
**create_method..manager_method() got multiple values for keyword argument 'sq_price'**

```
Traceback
project_clean {
'file': 'https://aaa.com/zzz.zip',
 'rent_tax': 1548,
 'sq': Decimal('325')}
sq_price: Decimal('4.763076923076923076923076923')
```

Comment: Does `detail_clean` also have a form input with the name `sq_price`? Can you show your `forms.py` ? Can you also post the full, original traceback?

Comment: I solved the problem. Django got confused, because he was getting data from template and function